# React with Semantic UI Multiple Search Dropdown Issue

Tags: reactjs

I think I hit a bug , may be something to do with Sematic UI. When I click onto the drop down and click again (not selecting anything, but just clicking onto the input field the Cursor goes away and now nothing can't be typed in. This can also be reproduced by typing in something random in the field and then click onto the input field again. The focus disappears and then nothing on the field could be edited.

https://react.semantic-ui.com/maximize/dropdown-example-multiple-search-selection/

Anyone can help me with this issue ?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely something on Semantic UI's end for this component specifically, because the other dropdowns work fine. If I had to guess, they are changing the focus to the first `div` in the list, which is preventing you from doing anything until it is selected or until the dropdown is closed.

You should be able to use the Multiple Selection dropdown and add an `input` tag inside the listbox `div` to create your own search functionality. Once you have the input inside the div, you could create your own search using state:

```
state = {
    search: ''
};
onInputChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
        search: event.target.value
    });
}
```

and your input would look like this:

```
<input type="text" value={ this.state.search } onChange={ this.onInputChange }
```